# Merge documents by inserting content into a new page using poi

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-poi

I have several documents and I want to combine them all into one docx file.
My code :

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTBody;

public class WordMerge {

private final OutputStream result;
private final List<InputStream> inputs;
private XWPFDocument first;

public WordMerge(OutputStream result) {
    this.result = result;
    inputs = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void add(InputStream stream) throws Exception{            
    inputs.add(stream);
    OPCPackage srcPackage = OPCPackage.open(stream);
    XWPFDocument src1Document = new XWPFDocument(srcPackage);         
    if(inputs.size() == 1){
        first = src1Document;
    } else {            
        CTBody srcBody = src1Document.getDocument().getBody();
        first.getDocument().addNewBody().set(srcBody);            
    }        
}

public void doMerge() throws Exception{
    first.write(result);                
}

public void close() throws Exception{
    result.flush();
    result.close();
    for (InputStream input : inputs) {
        input.close();
    }
}   
}
```

And it use :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

FileOutputStream faos = new FileOutputStream("/home/victor/result.docx");

WordMerge wm = new WordMerge(faos);

wm.add( new FileInputStream("/home/victor/001.docx") );
wm.add( new FileInputStream("/home/victor/002.docx") );

wm.doMerge();
wm.close();
}
```

It works, unfortunatly it becomes a bit messy if you have listings in any of the non-first document. Listing symbols change to numbers and worse sometimes a listing from the previous document will be continued in the attached document. Say doc1 has a.b.c listing , second has non ordered listing then this latter one becomes d.e.f. **(It followed the previous document formatting.)**

How to make each document that is merged on the next page and not follow the formatting of the previous document?

Comment: Your code only appends multiple `CTBody` elements   into the document. But that is not how a Word document is structured. "It works" because Microsoft Word is tolerant enough to interpret it. But it fails when it comes to references within the Word document structure. For example to numbering definitions, footnotes, endnotes, media (images for ex.), ... So that approach is not usable at all. The need is traversing all body elements of both the documents and append each body element to an new document and update it's references. This is much to broad to answer in one question here.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Do you have any reference for a more suitable approach to solve my problem?

Comment: Not that I know. Some of the paid closed source libraries claim to be able merging DOCX documents. But I've never had that problem. For me word-processing documents always are the end result, never a data exchange format. So the data source for a word-processing document never are single word-processing documents but real data sources as data bases or JSON or XML or CSV or else. Then one single word-processing document gets created from that data source. So no merging needed.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. But please help me because I have tried my best to find a solution but haven't found a suitable approach, do you have any other ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, how much time are you able to invest? As said, the need is traversing all body elements of both the documents and append each body element to an new document and update it's references. I could show you a working draft using `apache poi`. But I cannot deliver the ready to use code which merges Word documents and considers all possible content. If that is needed, then buy one of the commercial libraries(Aspose, ...,  or the MergeDocx utility, which is a paid extension to docx4j).

Comment: Then can you show me a working draft using apache poi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code only appends multiple `CTBody` elements into the document. But that is not how a Word document is structured. "It works" because Microsoft Word is tolerant enough to interpret it. But it fails when it comes to references within the Word document structure.

For example to numbering definitions are referenced by IDs. And that can be the same ID for different definitions in different documents. So ID 1 in first document might be pointing to a decimal numbering while ID 1 in second document might be pointing to a bullet numbering. So the numIDs needs to be merged and not only copied.

Embedded  media (images for ex.) are referenced by rIDs. So the `CTBody` only contains the IDs. The media itself is stored outside the document body. So if the document body refers to a picture having rID12 and this picture is not stored, then the document gets corrupted.

Same is with many other document elements.

So that approach is not usable at all.

The need is traversing all body elements of the document, which shall be appended. Then append each found body element to the first document and update it's references.

The following is a working draft to show the principle. It is not ready yet. For example it does not considering hyperlinks, footnotes, comments, structured document tags and much more things. And as you see from the sheer amount of code needed, considering all possible things will be a very laborious task to do. To avoid even more code I simply copy the underlying XML bean if possible. This also should be better formed out for productive usage. But the principle should be clear from this code.

The code is commented when names of methods and variables are not self explained.

The code is tested and works using current `apache poi 5.1.0`. Former versions are not tested and also should  not be used since they offer even less support for `XWPF`.

The code needs the full jar of all of the schemas as mentioned in [Apache POI FAQ](https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10025).

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class WordMerger {
    
 private Map<BigInteger, BigInteger> numIDs = null; // to handle merging numID 
 
 public WordMerger() {
  this.numIDs= new HashMap<BigInteger, BigInteger>();
 }
                
 private void traverseBodyElements(List<IBodyElement> bodyElements, IBody resultBody) throws Exception {
  for (IBodyElement bodyElement : bodyElements) {
   if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;
    XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = createParagraphWithPPr(paragraph, resultBody);
    traverseRunElements(paragraph.getIRuns(), resultParagraph);
   } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFSDT) {
    XWPFSDT sDT = (XWPFSDT)bodyElement;
    XWPFSDT resultSDT = createSDT(sDT, resultBody);
    //ToDo: handle further issues ...
   } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFTable) {
    XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable)bodyElement;
    XWPFTable resultTable = createTableWithTblPrAndTblGrid(table, resultBody);
    traverseTableRows(table.getRows(), resultTable);
   }
  }
 }

 private XWPFSDT createSDT(XWPFSDT sDT, IBody resultBody) {
  //not ready yet
  //we simply add paragraphs to avoid corruped documents
  if (resultBody instanceof XWPFDocument) {
   XWPFDocument resultDocument = (XWPFDocument)resultBody;
   XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = resultDocument.createParagraph();
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...
  } else if (resultBody instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
   XWPFTableCell resultTableCell = (XWPFTableCell)resultBody;
   XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = resultTableCell.addParagraph();
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...
  } //ToDo: else others ...
  //ToDo: handle SDT properly
  return null;
 }

 private XWPFParagraph createParagraphWithPPr(XWPFParagraph paragraph, IBody resultBody) {
  if (resultBody instanceof XWPFDocument) {
   XWPFDocument resultDocument = (XWPFDocument)resultBody;
   XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = resultDocument.createParagraph();
   resultParagraph.getCTP().setPPr(paragraph.getCTP().getPPr());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
   handleStyles(resultDocument, paragraph);
   handleNumberings(paragraph, resultParagraph);
   handleOMathParaArray(paragraph, resultParagraph);
   handleOMathIfFirstChild(paragraph, resultParagraph);
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...
   return resultParagraph;
  } else if (resultBody instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
   XWPFTableCell resultTableCell = (XWPFTableCell)resultBody;
   XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = resultTableCell.addParagraph();
   resultParagraph.getCTP().setPPr(paragraph.getCTP().getPPr());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
   handleStyles(resultTableCell, paragraph);
   handleOMathParaArray(paragraph, resultParagraph);
   handleOMathIfFirstChild(paragraph, resultParagraph);
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...  
   return resultParagraph;
  } //ToDo: else others ...
  return null;
 }

 private void handleOMathParaArray(XWPFParagraph paragraph, XWPFParagraph resultParagraph) {
  resultParagraph.getCTP().setOMathParaArray​(paragraph.getCTP().getOMathParaArray());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
 }
 
 private void handleOMathIfFirstChild(XWPFParagraph paragraph, XWPFParagraph resultParagraph) {
  org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
  cursor.toChild(0);
  org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xmlObject = cursor.getObject();
  if (xmlObject instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath) {
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath ctOMath = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath)xmlObject;
   resultParagraph.getCTP().addNewOMath();
   resultParagraph.getCTP().setOMathArray(resultParagraph.getCTP().getOMathArray().length-1, ctOMath);
  }  
 }
 
 private void handleNumberings(XWPFParagraph paragraph, XWPFParagraph resultParagraph) {
  //if we have numberings, we need merging the numIDs and abstract numberings of the two different documents
  BigInteger numID = paragraph.getNumID();
  if (numID == null) return;
  BigInteger resultNumID = this.numIDs.get(numID);
  if (resultNumID == null) {
   XWPFDocument document = paragraph.getDocument(); 
   XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();
   XWPFNum num = numbering.getNum(numID);
   BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.getAbstractNumID(numID);
   XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = numbering.getAbstractNum(abstractNumID);
   XWPFAbstractNum resultAbstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum((org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum)abstractNum.getCTAbstractNum().copy());
   XWPFDocument resultDocument = resultParagraph.getDocument(); 
   XWPFNumbering resultNumbering = resultDocument.createNumbering();
   int pos = resultNumbering.getAbstractNums().size();
   resultAbstractNum.getCTAbstractNum().setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(pos));
   BigInteger resultAbstractNumID = resultNumbering.addAbstractNum(resultAbstractNum);
   resultNumID = resultNumbering.addNum(resultAbstractNumID);
   XWPFNum resultNum = resultNumbering.getNum(resultNumID);
   resultNum.getCTNum().setLvlOverrideArray(num.getCTNum().getLvlOverrideArray());
   this.numIDs.put(numID, resultNumID);
  }
  resultParagraph.setNumID(resultNumID);  
 }

 private void handleStyles(IBody resultBody, IBodyElement bodyElement) {
  //if we have bodyElement styles we need merging those styles of the two different documents
  XWPFDocument document = null;
  String styleID = null;
  if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
   XWPFParagraph paragraph = (XWPFParagraph)bodyElement;  
   document = paragraph.getDocument(); 
   styleID = paragraph.getStyleID();   
  } else if (bodyElement instanceof XWPFTable) {
   XWPFTable table = (XWPFTable)bodyElement;
   if (table.getPart() instanceof XWPFDocument) {
    document = (XWPFDocument)table.getPart();
    styleID = table.getStyleID();
   }
  } //ToDo: else others ...
  if (document == null || styleID == null || "".equals(styleID)) return;
  XWPFDocument resultDocument = null;
  if (resultBody instanceof XWPFDocument) {
   resultDocument = (XWPFDocument)resultBody;
  } else if (resultBody instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
   XWPFTableCell resultTableCell = (XWPFTableCell)resultBody;
   resultDocument = resultTableCell.getXWPFDocument();
  } //ToDo: else others ...
  if (resultDocument != null) {
   XWPFStyles styles = document.getStyles();  
   XWPFStyles resultStyles = resultDocument.getStyles(); 
   XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyle(styleID);
   //merge each used styles, also the related ones
   for (XWPFStyle relatedStyle : styles.getUsedStyleList(style)) {
    if (resultStyles.getStyle(relatedStyle.getStyleId()) == null) {
     resultStyles.addStyle(relatedStyle);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 private XWPFTable createTableWithTblPrAndTblGrid(XWPFTable table, IBody resultBody) {
  if (resultBody instanceof XWPFDocument) {
   XWPFDocument resultDocument = (XWPFDocument)resultBody;
   XWPFTable resultTable = resultDocument.createTable();
   resultTable.removeRow(0);   
   resultTable.getCTTbl().setTblPr(table.getCTTbl().getTblPr());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
   resultTable.getCTTbl().setTblGrid(table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
   handleStyles(resultDocument, table);
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...
   return resultTable;
  } else if (resultBody instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
   //ToDo: handle stacked tables
  } //ToDo: else others ...
  return null;       
 }

 private void traverseRunElements(List<IRunElement> runElements, IRunBody resultRunBody) throws Exception {
  for (IRunElement runElement : runElements) {
   if (runElement instanceof XWPFFieldRun) {
    XWPFFieldRun fieldRun = (XWPFFieldRun)runElement;
    XWPFFieldRun resultFieldRun = createFieldRunWithRPr(fieldRun, resultRunBody);
    traversePictures(fieldRun, resultFieldRun);
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFHyperlinkRun) {
    XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun = (XWPFHyperlinkRun)runElement;
    XWPFHyperlinkRun resultHyperlinkRun = createHyperlinkRunWithRPr(hyperlinkRun, resultRunBody);
    traversePictures(hyperlinkRun, resultHyperlinkRun);
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
    XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun)runElement;
    XWPFRun resultRun = createRunWithRPr(run, resultRunBody);
    traversePictures(run, resultRun);
   } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFSDT) {
    XWPFSDT sDT = (XWPFSDT)runElement;
    //ToDo: handle SDT
   }
  }
 }

 private void copyTextOfRuns(XWPFRun run, XWPFRun resultRun) {
  //copy all of the possible T contents of the runs
  for (int i = 0; i < run.getCTR().sizeOfTArray(); i++) {
   resultRun.setText(run.getText(i), i);
  }
 }
 
 private XWPFFieldRun createFieldRunWithRPr(XWPFFieldRun fieldRun, IRunBody resultRunBody) {
  if (resultRunBody instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
   XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = (XWPFParagraph)resultRunBody;
   XWPFFieldRun resultFieldRun = (XWPFFieldRun)resultParagraph.createRun();
   resultFieldRun.getCTR().setRPr(fieldRun.getCTR().getRPr());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
   //ToDo: handle field runs properly ...
   handleRunStyles(resultParagraph.getDocument(), fieldRun);
   handlePossibleOMtáth(fieldRun, resultRunBody);
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...
   return resultFieldRun;
  } else if (resultRunBody instanceof XWPFSDT) {   
   //ToDo: handle SDT
  }
  return null;
 }
 
 private XWPFHyperlinkRun createHyperlinkRunWithRPr(XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun, IRunBody resultRunBody) {
  if (resultRunBody instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
   XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = (XWPFParagraph)resultRunBody;
   org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink resultCTHyperLink = resultParagraph.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
   resultCTHyperLink.addNewR();
   XWPFHyperlinkRun resultHyperlinkRun =  new XWPFHyperlinkRun(resultCTHyperLink, resultCTHyperLink.getRArray(0), resultParagraph);
   if (hyperlinkRun.getAnchor() != null) {
    resultHyperlinkRun = resultParagraph.createHyperlinkRun(hyperlinkRun.getAnchor());
   }
   resultHyperlinkRun.getCTR().setRPr(hyperlinkRun.getCTR().getRPr());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
   copyTextOfRuns(hyperlinkRun, resultHyperlinkRun);
   //ToDo: handle external hyperlink runs properly ...
   handleRunStyles(resultParagraph.getDocument(), hyperlinkRun);
   handlePossibleOMtáth(hyperlinkRun, resultRunBody);
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...
   return resultHyperlinkRun;
  } else if (resultRunBody instanceof XWPFSDT) {   
   //ToDo: handle SDT
  }
  return null;
 }

 private XWPFRun createRunWithRPr(XWPFRun run, IRunBody resultRunBody) {
  if (resultRunBody instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
   XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = (XWPFParagraph)resultRunBody;
   XWPFRun resultRun = resultParagraph.createRun();
   resultRun.getCTR().setRPr(run.getCTR().getRPr());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
   copyTextOfRuns(run, resultRun);
   handleRunStyles(resultParagraph.getDocument(), run);
   handlePossibleOMtáth(run, resultRunBody);
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...
   return resultRun;
  } else if (resultRunBody instanceof XWPFSDT) {   
   //ToDo: handle SDT
  }
  return null;
 }

 private void handlePossibleOMtáth(XWPFRun run, IRunBody resultRunBody) {
  if (resultRunBody instanceof XWPFParagraph) {
   XWPFParagraph resultParagraph = (XWPFParagraph)resultRunBody;
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor cursor = run.getCTR().newCursor();
   cursor.toNextSibling();
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xmlObject = cursor.getObject();
   if (xmlObject instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath) {
    org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath ctOMath = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.officeDocument.x2006.math.CTOMath)xmlObject;
    resultParagraph.getCTP().addNewOMath();
    resultParagraph.getCTP().setOMathArray(resultParagraph.getCTP().getOMathArray().length-1, ctOMath);
   }  
  } else if (resultRunBody instanceof XWPFSDT) {   
   //ToDo: handle SDT
  }
 }
 
 private void handleRunStyles(IBody resultBody, IRunElement runElement) {
  //if we have runElement styles we need merging those styles of the two different documents
  XWPFDocument document = null;
  String styleID = null;
  if (runElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
   XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun)runElement;  
   document = run.getDocument(); 
   styleID = run.getStyle();   
  } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFHyperlinkRun) {
   XWPFHyperlinkRun run = (XWPFHyperlinkRun)runElement;  
   document = run.getDocument(); 
   styleID = run.getStyle();      
  } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFFieldRun) {
   XWPFFieldRun run = (XWPFFieldRun)runElement;  
   document = run.getDocument(); 
   styleID = run.getStyle();      
  } //ToDo: else others ...
  if (document == null || styleID == null || "".equals(styleID)) return;
  XWPFDocument resultDocument = null;
  if (resultBody instanceof XWPFDocument) {
   resultDocument = (XWPFDocument)resultBody;
  } else if (resultBody instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
   XWPFTableCell resultTableCell = (XWPFTableCell)resultBody;
   resultDocument = resultTableCell.getXWPFDocument();
  } //ToDo: else others ...
  if (resultDocument != null) {
   XWPFStyles styles = document.getStyles();  
   XWPFStyles resultStyles = resultDocument.getStyles(); 
   XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyle(styleID);
   //merge each used styles, also the related ones
   for (XWPFStyle relatedStyle : styles.getUsedStyleList(style)) {
    if (resultStyles.getStyle(relatedStyle.getStyleId()) == null) {
     resultStyles.addStyle(relatedStyle);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 private void traverseTableRows(List<XWPFTableRow> tableRows, XWPFTable resultTable) throws Exception {
  for (XWPFTableRow tableRow : tableRows) {
   XWPFTableRow resultTableRow = createTableRowWithTrPr(tableRow, resultTable);
   traverseTableCells(tableRow.getTableICells(), resultTableRow);
  }
 }

 private XWPFTableRow createTableRowWithTrPr(XWPFTableRow tableRow, XWPFTable resultTable) {
  XWPFTableRow resultTableRow = resultTable.createRow();
  for (int i = resultTableRow.getTableCells().size(); i > 0; i--) { //table row should be empty at first
   resultTableRow.removeCell(i-1);
  }
  resultTableRow.getCtRow().setTrPr(tableRow.getCtRow().getTrPr());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
  //ToDo: handle further issues ...
  return resultTableRow;
 }

 private void traverseTableCells(List<ICell> tableICells, XWPFTableRow resultTableRow) throws Exception {
  for (ICell tableICell : tableICells) {
   if (tableICell instanceof XWPFSDTCell) {
    XWPFSDTCell sDTCell = (XWPFSDTCell)tableICell;
    XWPFSDTCell resultSdtTableCell = createSdtTableCell(sDTCell, resultTableRow);
    //ToDo: handle further issues ...  
   } else if (tableICell instanceof XWPFTableCell) {
    XWPFTableCell tableCell = (XWPFTableCell)tableICell;
    XWPFTableCell resultTableCell = createTableCellWithTcPr(tableCell, resultTableRow);
    traverseBodyElements(tableCell.getBodyElements(), resultTableCell);
   }
  }
 }

 private XWPFSDTCell createSdtTableCell(XWPFSDTCell sDTCell, XWPFTableRow resultTableRow) { 
  //create at least a cell to avoid corrupted document
  XWPFTableCell resultTableCell = resultTableRow.createCell();
  //ToDo: handle SDTCell properly
  //ToDo: handle further issues ...
  return null;
 }
 
 private XWPFTableCell createTableCellWithTcPr(XWPFTableCell tableCell, XWPFTableRow resultTableRow) { 
  XWPFTableCell resultTableCell = resultTableRow.createCell();
  resultTableCell.removeParagraph(0);
  resultTableCell.getCTTc().setTcPr(tableCell.getCTTc().getTcPr());//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
  //ToDo: handle further issues ...
  return resultTableCell;
 }

 private void traversePictures(IRunElement runElement, IRunElement resultRunElement) throws Exception { 
  List<XWPFPicture> pictures = null;
  if (runElement instanceof XWPFFieldRun) {
   XWPFFieldRun fieldRun = (XWPFFieldRun)runElement;
   pictures = fieldRun.getEmbeddedPictures();
  } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFHyperlinkRun) {
   XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun = (XWPFHyperlinkRun)resultRunElement;
   pictures = hyperlinkRun.getEmbeddedPictures();
  } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
   XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun)runElement;
   pictures = run.getEmbeddedPictures();
  } else if (runElement instanceof XWPFSDT) {
   XWPFSDT sDT = (XWPFSDT)runElement;
   //ToDo: handle SDT
  }            
  if (pictures != null) { 
   for (XWPFPicture picture : pictures) {
    XWPFPictureData pictureData = picture.getPictureData();
    XWPFPicture resultPicture = createPictureWithDrawing(runElement, picture, pictureData, resultRunElement);
   }
  }
 }

 private XWPFPicture createPictureWithDrawing(IRunElement runElement, XWPFPicture picture, XWPFPictureData pictureData, IRunElement resultRunElement) {
  if (resultRunElement instanceof XWPFFieldRun) {
   XWPFFieldRun fieldRun = (XWPFFieldRun)runElement;
   XWPFFieldRun resultFieldRun = (XWPFFieldRun)resultRunElement;
   XWPFPicture resultPicture = createPictureWithDrawing(fieldRun, resultFieldRun, picture, pictureData);
   return resultPicture;
  } else if (resultRunElement instanceof XWPFHyperlinkRun) {
   XWPFHyperlinkRun hyperlinkRun = (XWPFHyperlinkRun)runElement;
   XWPFHyperlinkRun resultHyperlinkRun = (XWPFHyperlinkRun)resultRunElement;
   XWPFPicture resultPicture = createPictureWithDrawing(hyperlinkRun, resultHyperlinkRun, picture, pictureData);
   return resultPicture;
  } else if (resultRunElement instanceof XWPFRun) {
   XWPFRun run = (XWPFRun)runElement;
   XWPFRun resultRun = (XWPFRun)resultRunElement;
   XWPFPicture resultPicture = createPictureWithDrawing(run, resultRun, picture, pictureData);
   return resultPicture;
  } else if (resultRunElement instanceof XWPFSDT) {
   XWPFSDT sDT = (XWPFSDT)resultRunElement;
   //ToDo: handle SDT
  }            
  return null; 
 }
 
 private XWPFPicture createPictureWithDrawing(XWPFRun run, XWPFRun resultRun, XWPFPicture picture, XWPFPictureData pictureData) {
  try {
   XWPFPicture resultPicture = resultRun.addPicture(
    pictureData.getPackagePart().getInputStream(), 
    pictureData.getPictureType(), 
    pictureData.getFileName(), 
    Units.pixelToEMU((int)picture.getWidth()), 
    Units.pixelToEMU((int)picture.getDepth()));
   String rId = resultPicture.getCTPicture().getBlipFill().getBlip().getEmbed();
   resultRun.getCTR().setDrawingArray(0, run.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0));//simply copy the underlying XML bean to avoid more code
   //but then correct the rID
   String declareNameSpaces = "declare namespace a='http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main'; ";
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject[] selectedObjects = resultRun.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0).selectPath(
    declareNameSpaces 
    + "$this//a:blip");
   for (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject blipObject : selectedObjects) {
    if (blipObject instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTBlip) {
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTBlip blip = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTBlip)blipObject;
     if (blip.isSetEmbed()) blip.setEmbed(rId);
    }
   }
   //remove rIDs to external hyperlinks to avoid corruot document
   selectedObjects = resultRun.getCTR().getDrawingArray(0).selectPath(
    declareNameSpaces 
    + "$this//a:hlinkClick");
   for (org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject hlinkClickObject : selectedObjects) {
    if (hlinkClickObject instanceof org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink) {
     org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink hlinkClick = (org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink)hlinkClickObject;
     if (hlinkClick.isSetId()) hlinkClick.setId("");
     //ToDo: handle pictures having hyperlinks properly
    }
   }
   //ToDo: handle further issues ...
   return resultPicture;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
 }

 public void merge(String firstFilePath, String secondFilePath, String resultFilePath) throws Exception {
  XWPFDocument resultDocument = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(firstFilePath));
  XWPFDocument documentToAppend = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(secondFilePath));
  traverseBodyElements(documentToAppend.getBodyElements(), resultDocument);
  documentToAppend.close();
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(resultFilePath);
  resultDocument.write(out);
  out.close();
  resultDocument.close();
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  WordMerger merger = new WordMerger();
  merger.merge("./WordDocument3.docx", "./WordDocument4.docx", "./WordDocumentResult.docx");
 }
}
```

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you very much. But there is still something missing in the numbering. I got an error in function handleNumberings(), exactly in the .getAbstractNums(), is there something wrong there?

Comment: @Jessica Cathrine: What exact error? What exact `apache poi` version used?

Comment: This is the error message :
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getAbstractNums()
  location: variable resultNumbering of type org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFNumbering

I use apache poi version 4.1.2

Comment: @Jessica Cathrine: See my answer: "The code is tested and works using current apache poi 5.1.0. Former versions are not tested and also should not be used since they offer even less support for XWPF."

Comment: I'm already using version 5.1.0, but still error in method getAbstractNums(). Can you show me your pom.xml file?

Comment: @Jessica Cathrine: All I can tell is that `XWPFNumbering` is contained in `poi-ooxml-5.1.0.jar`. Dependency: `...<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId><version>5.1.0</version> ...`. And there must not be other `poi-ooxml` versions in class path.

Comment: Thank youu very muchh Axel

Comment: Hi Axel, this works like a charm (Apache POI 5.2.2), thanks for sharing! I also have some basic charts in my word documents which I want to append.  Is this an easy functionality to add?

Comment: @Ivo Sturm: "Is this an easy functionality to add?": No, not easy to add. Charts are not body elements for Apache POI until now.

Comment: Hi Axel, thanks for the quick reply. Do you have an idea on how to achieve this? I will be diving into it. Any hint from an expert like you would be helpful!

Comment: @Ivo Sturm:  Create a `*.docx` file containing a chart. The unzip that `*.docx` file and have a look into `/word/document.xml`. Look how the chart appears into the document body XML. You will find it in a drawing in a run element. Try to understand how my code handles pictures in drawings in run elements. Then adopt that to handle charts in drawings in run elements.

Comment: @AxelRichter currently the position of the table within the to be merged documents isn't kept, the tables of the to be copied Word documents are just appended at the next line available in the base Word document. Is there a way to keep the positioning? For text it is going fine though...