# Storing MS Word XML data into XWPFDocument ( apache POI)

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, apache-poi

Can anyone help , I've been trying to store the MS Word format  XML data into XWPFDocument of Apache Poi
But it is giving me error
here is the code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public class WordMerger {

public static void main(String[] args) {

try {
Open the first document
XWPFDocument doc1 = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("document1.xml"));

Open the second document
XWPFDocument doc2 = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("document2.xml"));

Iterate through the paragraphs of the second document
for (XWPFParagraph p : doc2.getParagraphs()) {

Create a new paragraph in the first document
XWPFParagraph newParagraph = doc1.createParagraph();

Iterate through the runs of the current paragraph in the second document
for (XWPFRun r : p.getRuns()) {

Create a new run in the new paragraph of the first document
XWPFRun newRun = newParagraph.createRun();

Copy the text and formatting of the current run to the new run
newRun.setText(r.getText(0));
newRun.setBold(r.isBold());
newRun.setItalic(r.isItalic());
newRun.setUnderline(r.getUnderline());
newRun.setColor(r.getColor());
newRun.setFontFamily(r.getFontFamily());
newRun.setFontSize(r.getFontSize());
                }
            }

Save the merged document
doc1.write(new FileOutputStream("merged_document.xml"));

Close the documents
doc1.close();
doc2.close();

System.out.println("Documents merged successfully!");

catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

is their any way i can read the file and store in it

Comment: What let you think, that `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument` is able processing `*.xml` files? This class is made to process `*.docx` files, nothing else.

Comment: I'm new to Apache POI; if you know which library or jar files are utilised,  please Can you tell me

Comment: What is the goal? Merging two `*.docx` documents? If so, then manipulation the XML directly is the wrong approach. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648296/merge-documents-by-inserting-content-into-a-new-page-using-poi/70700519#70700519.

Comment: i have MS word format xml files, i guess which is aslo called Open Xml File stored in database , just want merge  the multiple MS word format  XML file into one docx file

Comment: A OpenXML format file is a ZIP archive containing XML files and other files (embedded pictures for ex.) in a special directory structure. So what you have (`document1.xml`, `document2.xml`, ...) are only parts of the Word file and not the whole Word file. And `XWPFDocument` is only able processing whole Word file. It is not able processing only parts of a Word file.

Comment: is their any way i can convert just  document.xml into word ?????

Comment: No, not that I am aware of. The given `document.xml` might refer styles, themes, headers, footers, footnotes, numberings, ... which one cannot determine from that given `document.xml` alone.