# How to parse and print bulleted list using Apache POI?

Tags: java, ms-word, xml-parsing, apache-poi, xwpf

I am trying to extract entire word document in Java project, go paragraph by paragraph and print the XWPFParagraphs back to another word file.
I am able to accomplish my task except the bulleted list from input document is being printed as numbered list in the output document.

[image: input list]
[image: output list is being printed as numbered list; I want it as same as the input document]

This is the code where I am copying the paragraph:

```
static void copyParagraph(XWPFParagraph source, XWPFParagraph target, XWPFNumbering numbering)
    {
        target.getCTP().setPPr(source.getCTP().getPPr());

        source.getRuns().forEach(run -> {
            XWPFRun newR = target.createRun();
            newR.setText(run.getText(0));
            newR.getCTR().setRPr(run.getCTR().getRPr());

            if (!run.getEmbeddedPictures().isEmpty()) {
                XWPFPicture picture = run.getEmbeddedPictures().get(0);
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Constants.H1_SECTIONS_IMAGE_DIR + picture.getPictureData().getFileName());
                    out.write(picture.getPictureData().getData());
                    out.close();
                    newR.addPicture(new FileInputStream(Constants.H1_SECTIONS_IMAGE_DIR + picture.getPictureData().getFileName()), picture.getPictureData().getPictureType(), picture.getPictureData().getFileName(), Units.toEMU((int) picture.getWidth()), Units.toEMU((int) picture.getDepth()));
                } catch (IOException | InvalidFormatException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am not able to find solution which can keep the same list-type (bullet, numbered, etc) in the output document

Comment: You need copying the numbering definitions too. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648296/merge-documents-by-inserting-content-into-a-new-page-using-poi/70700519#70700519 for an example. It merges documents. But that also means copying elements.