# copy a xwpftablecell to another xwpftablecell of new table with it's equations and pictures

Tags: java, image, apache-poi, equation

I am building a **java** code using apache poi to read a .docx word file and generate another .docx word file. I have to copy a **XWPFTableCell** to another **XWPFTableCell** exactly. This **XWPFTableCell** may contains math equations, chemistry formulas along with pictures.

here is a sample of **XWPFTableCell**

*some text here ... **equation, formula**, some text here ..., **an image** some text here ...*

[Sample of the XWPFTableCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiVmu.png)

INPUT (format is *.docx)

[Sample of the XWPFTableCell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnQag.png)

How can copy the XWPFTableCell to new XWPFTableCell of the new .doxc file with its original form(contents). ( fisrtly I tried to read the cell and write to database, but I failed)

OUTPUT (format is *.docx)

here is my code

```
public ApiResponse generateDocument(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    try (XWPFDocument targetDoc = new XWPFDocument()){
        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        XWPFDocument courseDoc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("upload/yukla.docx"));

        XWPFTable targetTable = targetDoc.createTable(10, 5);
        for (IBodyElement ibodyelement : courseDoc.getBodyElements()) {
            if (ibodyelement instanceof XWPFTable courseTable) {
                cloneTable(courseTable, targetTable);
            }
        }

        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=VARIANTS.docx");
        FileCopyUtils.copy(b.toByteArray(), response.getOutputStream());
        targetDoc.write(b);
        courseDoc.close();
        targetDoc.close();
        return new ApiResponse("SUCCESS", true);
    }
}

private void cloneTable(XWPFTable courseTable, XWPFTable targetTable) {
    int cntRow = 0;
    for (XWPFTableRow row : courseTable.getRows()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            XWPFTableCell courseCell = row.getCell(i);
            XWPFTableCell targetCell = targetTable.getRow(cntRow).getCell(i);
            cloneCell(courseCell, targetCell);
        }
        cntRow++;
    }
}

private void cloneCell(XWPFTableCell courseCell, XWPFTableCell targetCell) {
    for (XWPFParagraph coursePr : courseCell.getParagraphs()) {
        XWPFParagraph targetPr = targetCell.addParagraph();
        cloneParagraph(targetPr, coursePr);
    }
}

private void cloneParagraph(XWPFParagraph clone, XWPFParagraph source) {
    CTPPr pPr = clone.getCTP().isSetPPr() ? clone.getCTP().getPPr() : clone.getCTP().addNewPPr();
    pPr.set(source.getCTP().getPPr());
    for (XWPFRun r : source.getRuns()) {
        XWPFRun nr = clone.createRun();
        cloneRun(nr, r);
    }
}

private void cloneRun(XWPFRun clone, XWPFRun source) {
    CTRPr rPr = clone.getCTR().isSetRPr() ? clone.getCTR().getRPr() : clone.getCTR().addNewRPr();
    rPr.set(source.getCTR().getRPr());
    clone.setText(source.getText(0));
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Apache POI is incomplete in this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648296/merge-documents-by-inserting-content-into-a-new-page-using-poi/70700519#70700519 for an example which copies body elements from one document to another and considers underlying low level elements.