# How to read text from docx with word equations included and paste it in another docx file

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, mathml

I tried to read docx file using Apache POI on java but XWPFParagraph type cant contain Math ML word equations. I don't know how they are written in the docx file. I heard that they're look like xml code.
How can I read the entire line that will contain both text and Math ML equations and then paste into another docx without losing the original look of the line and equations? Preferably by means of Apache poi, of course.

Comment: Apache POI is not able to do this up to now using only its high level user model objects. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648296/merge-documents-by-inserting-content-into-a-new-page-using-poi/70700519#70700519 to get an idea of the challemge. This tries merging two Word documents bu that also needs copying body elemens form one document to the other. So maybe you get inspiration from that.

Comment: In general, Word documents are not at the data storage layer for me, but at the presentation layer. So the need to extract data from a Word document for use elsewhere shouldn't arise in the first place. Data should be in a database for example. And the requirement should only be to **present** them in a Word document, for example.