use Apache POI copy Header Footer to another word document lose style
use Apache POI copy Header Footer to another word document lose style.
Copy method:
public static void copyHeaderFooter(XWPFDocument targetDocument, XWPFDocument templateDocument) {
        XWPFHeaderFooter[] headerFooterTemplate = getHeaderFooterTemplate(templateDocument);
        XWPFHeader templateHeader = (XWPFHeader) headerFooterTemplate[0];
        XWPFFooter templateFooter = (XWPFFooter) headerFooterTemplate[1];
        XWPFHeader hdr = targetDocument.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
        XWPFFooter ftr = targetDocument.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
        hdr.setHeaderFooter(templateHeader._getHdrFtr());
        ftr.setHeaderFooter(templateFooter._getHdrFtr());
}

both two word document with same paragraph styles,is work normal.
on haven't same styles,merge result is chaos.
I haven't method to fix it.

"... on haven't same styles, merge result is chaos": Well, the need is to copy the styles too and not only the underlying XML of org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHdrFtr. But thats not as easy as you might think. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648296/merge-documents-by-inserting-content-into-a-new-page-using-poi/70700519#70700519 for an example merging document bodies. That could be adopted to header and footer document parts.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

thans for your answer，i've adjusted the feature design to avoid this problem.
